# Dynamically pull in dependencies for angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, gulp

So I am working with a couple of different Angular starter kits, but I have yet to find one that automatically puts in the script src, for the vendor resources such as angular formly, bootstrap, etc., in the index.html. I am trying to make it so my dependencies in my module can work.

Anyone know of any good grunt or gulp build that would take care of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) is what you are looking for. It will inject your bower dependencies into your 'index.html'.

however if you are trying to include JS dependencies into a stand-alone angular module meant to be used with different HTML applications, you will need to concatenate those dependencies into a single deployable JS file. This can be easily done with [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).